# In Outlook 2010, how do you search all messages sent on weekends?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search

For a specific period, last 3 months, how do I find all the messages that were sent (or received) on a weekend?

Is there a filter for this or does it need some workaround?

Comment: One specific weekend only? Or all weekend emails?

Answer (score 1):

Under "Search" tab, search "Tools" -> "Advanced Find", then "Advanced" tab - and under Define more criteria dropdown select "Date/Time Fields" -> "Sent", Condition to "Between", and Value to "<start Date> and <end Date>", then under "Browse", make sure you check "Include Subfolders", then "Find Now".

Comment: But will this only include weekends. I guess, no. It will include all mails between 2 dates, which is trivial to search.

Answer (score -1):

type this into your search bar with whatever other criteria you want.

received:sunday,saturday

[outlook search criteria web link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da)
[outlook search criteria screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG9Ax.jpg)

Comment: When filtering by weekdays, it only applies to the CURRENT week, so it doesn't answer the OP question.